# What does RHPort mean in tinyusb?

Tags: usb

Looking through tinyusb, am a bit confused on the meaning of RHPort - cannot find much on Internet, grepping through source gives me results like:

```
tinyusb/docs/info/changelog.rst:- Add rhport to hcd_init()
tinyusb/docs/info/changelog.rst:  - Support multiple usb ports with rhport=1 is high
...
tinyusb/examples/device/cdc_dual_ports/src/tusb_config.h:// RHPort max operational speed can defined by board.mk
...
tinyusb/examples/device/cdc_dual_ports/src/tusb_config.h:// Device mode with rhport and speed defined by board.mk
...
tinyusb/examples/device/cdc_msc/src/tusb_config.h:// RHPort number used for device can be defined by board.mk, default to port 0
...
```

... and trying to think of what could "RH" possibly stand for as an acronym, the only thing that pops in my head is "Right Honourable" `:)`

So, what is the meaning of `RHPort` in (tiny)USB?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found at least some sort of an explanation ...

Anyways, https://docs.tinyusb.org/en/latest/reference/getting_started.html says:

> Port Selection
>
> If a board has several ports, one port is chosen by default in the
> individual board.mk file. Use option PORT=x To choose another port.
> For example to select the HS port of a STM32F746Disco board, use:
>
> ```
> $ make BOARD=stm32f746disco PORT=1 all
> ```

A bit tricky to find where that `PORT` is used, then - but for the above example, it is most likely in https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb/blob/master/hw/bsp/stm32f7/family.mk :

```
...
CFLAGS += \
...
  -DBOARD_TUD_RHPORT=$(PORT)
...
```

... which then gets used in e.g. https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb/blob/master/examples/device/dfu_runtime/src/main.c :

```c
...
  // init device stack on configured roothub port
  tud_init(BOARD_TUD_RHPORT);
...
```

... which reveals, that "RH" in "RHPort" most likely stands for "Root Hub".

So, my guess is, that for boards that have multiple physical USB port connectors, the `RHPort` determines which of those ports is tinyusb targeting?